# How do I detect if MFSU has half below energy

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-industrialcraft, minecraft-direwolf20

I'm running number of nuclear reactor and I want to shut down MFSU have enough energy and start up not enough energy.

Nuclear reactor will waste fuel cell if connected MFSU already have fully charged, and I have Industrial information panel showing how much MFSU charged. I'm tired of manually switching levers on nuclear reactor.

Are there anyway detect MFSU(MFE) unit have half energy?

I'm using direwolf20's 1.6 version modpack.

It seems to be ComputerCraft could be a solution
[image]

[image]

Edited : I found some workaround. Anyone know better idea? I'm pretty new to computercraft and lua so I don't want to use it.
[image]

Comment: Hmm, do BuildCraft gates work with IndustrialCraft items?

Comment: Yes, 'capacitor empty', 'capacitor full', 'capacitor has energy', 'space for energy', 'charging empty item', 'charging fully charged item', 'charging partially charged item', 'discharging empty item', 'discharging fully charged item', ''discharging partially charged item'

Comment: does a vanilla comparator work on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 solutions:

### Method 1

I know you said you didn't want to use ComputerCraft however it's a more adaptable way than the other if you want to add more MFSU's. If you do, comment and I'll respond with info on how to. Put down a computer and do

`edit reactor`

In this file put:

```
mfe = peripheral.wrap("side")
while true do
  euPercent = mfe.getEUStored() / mfe.getEUCapacity()
  if euPercent==1 then
    redstone.setOutput("side", false)
  elseif euPercent<=.5 then
    redstone.setOutput("side", true)
  end
  sleep(1)
end
```

Save by hitting CTRL, selecting "Save" with the arrows, and hitting ENTER. Hit CTRL again, select "Exit" with the arrows, and hit ENTER.

Let's explain what that does:

`mfe = peripheral.wrap("side")` assigns the mfsu variable to `peripheral.wrap("side")`. Make sure to replace side with the side the MFSU is on.

`while true do` starts a while loop. This will do the code inside every tick unless there is a sleep.

`euPercent = mfsu.getEUStored() / mfsu.getEUCapacity()` reads the EU and divides it by the total capacity to get a decimal out of the total.

`if euPercent==1 then` checks if the MFSU is full. If it is, it runs any code till an `else` or `end`.

`redstone.setOutput("side", false)` sets the redstone output being emitted from `side` to false, turning off the reactors. Make sure you change side to the side which the redstone leading to your reactors is.

`else if euPercent<=.5 then` ends the code run by the previous if and starts an `else if`. This will, if the previous if is false, tests for if the if is true and if so, behaves the same as the if above.

`redstone.setOutput("side", true)` sets the redstone output being emitted from `side` to true, turning on the reactors. Make sure you change side to the side which the redstone leading to your reactors is.

`sleep(1)` waits for 1 second before going to the top of the while loop and running it all again.

Next, do `edit startup`. This will create a file run on startup of the computer. In it put:

```
 shell.run("reactor")
```

This means that on startup the reactor file created earlier will have the code in it run.

### Method 2

Use a BuildCraft gate to detect when the MFSU is full and output a redstone signal. Then, invert this with a redstone torch. I'll add more details when I can(tommrow EST at like 9 AM).

Comment: Thank you for descriptive method 1 and you don't need method 2 further.(I don't want to waste your effort :) ) I already knew it. cobblestone structure pipe and iron gate and red wire from buildcraft. Or framed red alloy wire with not gate from project|red.

Comment: @Zaphod Mind marking this as correct?

Comment: btw i blew up my world yesterday using this technique