# Im getting a error message in my computercraft computer

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-computercraft

I'm using this code from [How do I detect if MFSU has half below energy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/162187/how-do-i-detect-if-mfsu-has-half-below-energy), from [an answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/162268/4163) about half way down the page:

```
mfe = peripheral.wrap("left")
while true do
  euPercent = mfe.getEUStored() / mfe.getEUCapacity()
  if euPercent==1 then
    redstone.setOutput("right", false)
  elseif euPercent<=.5 then
    redstone.setOutput("right", true)
  end
  sleep(1)
end
```

This is so that I can have my computer turn off my nuclear reactor when it's full of power and on when it's not full, but when I run the program it says

```
reactor:3: attempt to index ? (a nil value)
```

Comment: this is where i got the code from http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/162187/how-do-i-detect-if-mfsu-has-half-below-energy its about half way down the page

Comment: is side a valid value? Shouldn't it be left or right?

Comment: Sorry about that, forgot to mention that i did replace the side parts of the code. This is what it looks like in my computer [IMG]http://i60.tinypic.com/i3cgb7.png[/IMG] i still get the error

Comment: Have you tried changing left and right? Maybe you just got it the wrong way around.

Answer (score 3):

`periphera.wrap()` is returning `nil` and storing that in `mfe`. That's a problem, and why it fails to be useful when you try to access it on line 3.

It's hard to figure out why from a distance. Three reasons I can think of are:

1. That the "side" argument to `wrap()` is incorrect and there's nothing on that side, which would make the [API deliberately return `nil`](http://computercraft.info/wiki/Peripheral.wrap) to alert you to the lack of peripheral.
2. CC does not understand IC2 blocks natively, and requires a mod to make it able to use IC2 blocks as peripherals — if you don't have one installed, the MFE would count as "nothing" to `wrap()` and it will return `nil`. [OpenCCSensors](http://www.computercraft.info/wiki/OpenCCSensors) is one such mod.
3. Another reason might be that [somewhere before this code runs `peripheral` has been overwritten in some way](http://www.computercraft.info/forums2/index.php?/topic/20889-peripheral-wrap-in-api-not-working/), making the call to `wrap()` return `nil`.

Comment: [IMG]http://i61.tinypic.com/33lnslw.png[/IMG] These two images should help for you too see the sides and the code. also keep in mine i know my left and right but i changed them around for a second to check if it would work in reverse

Comment: @Quelia I have a third suspicion then: you don't have the necessary CC addon mod installed to let CC talk to IC2 blocks.

Comment: Questions like this are confusing. It's about a function in game, so it's valid on Arqade, but it's a coding problem, which would make it valid on SO as well haha

Answer (score 0):

Where you got your code from, it says zo replace "side" with the side you have mfe/reactor on.